# App to measure the tempo of music

Tags: windows, gratis, music-recognition

I would like to arrange music to run to, such that the tempo of it increases as time passes.

Slow music is fine at the start, but could be deadly towards the end when my stamina is draining; I need something with a beat then.

The idea is that I choose the tracks and the app helps me arrange them in order of increasing tempo.

Must be free, prefer Widows, Linux ok, Android as a last resort.

MP3, OGG, FLAC; I don't mind converting to suit the app

Comment: https://jog.fm/ seems pretty good, but it doesn't search my music collection, just lists songs. Might be of some future help to others too. Caters for running, cycling & walking

Answer (score 1):

Measuring BPM *Beats Per Minute* is a tricky issue - several of the Apps that I have found rely on you tapping the screen, keyboard or mouse in time to the music to detect the actual beats which is not ideal.

I did find lots of discussion on how to do it and a web site that claims to know the BPM of **every** track https://songbpm.com/ - not sure that the claim of knowing them all is 100% accurate - the only down side is you need to know the Artist & Title for it to work.  The web site bases its data on Spotify so it should cover a very wide range of tracks - just as a test I tried `George Formby - When I'm Cleaning Windows` and it did give me a result but it failed on `Laurel and Hardy - Blue Ridge Mountains` so mixed results for some really old tracks, I guess it depends on which tracks you are looking at.

Comment: Plus one for your taste in music :-)  Some excellent resources there. No app, so I will have to code my own. Perhaps that's my next money maker? :-)

Comment: https://jog.fm/ seems pretty good, but it doesn't search my music collection, just lists songs. Might be of some future help to others too. Caters for running, cycling & walking.  I guess that I could code an app to measure that, or your https://songbpm.com/ to my music collection

Answer (score 1):

Definitely overkill but [Mixxx](http://www.mixxx.org/) 2.0.0 includes a BPM detection and estimation and Bulk BPM analysis tool.

The reason that I say Overkill is Mixxx is a full DJs Mixing desk with a lot of other features.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source (GPL).
- Cross Platform - OS-X, Win & Linux
- Corrections available for incorrectly detected beats, (see [manual](http://www.mixxx.org/manual/latest/chapters/configuration.html#bpm-and-beat-detection-preferences)).
- Saves the beat detection results to a "[beatgrid](http://www.mixxx.org/manual/latest/glossary.html#term-beatgrid)" but with a quick study of the source code &/or some enquires in the [forums](http://www.mixxx.org/forums/) you should be able to extract this information for other uses.

Comment: That's very good (for me). As you say, I can quickly analyze the  save file format, parse it and wrap an app around it. Just strange that there's isn't an app that you can command "take these tracks and sort them into an order for me to run to"